# Flashloan in JavaScript

Tags: flash-loans

Is it possible to request for a flashloan for use exclusively in Javascript as opposed to in the smart contract back-end?
I have a use case need to perform some adhoc logic based on received flashloaned asset wihtin JavaScript rather than in the smart contract back-end.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You mean `flashloan` involving off-chain javascript code? The answer is **No**. The mechanism of `flashloan` is that it must be completed in a single transaction. At the beginning of the transaction the Service lends you money without collateral, and at the end of that transaction the Service will take back the money you owed. If you have extra javascript logic or anything offchain, it means the flashloan tx has ended and you already paid back the borrowed amount. The only way is to implement all of your ad-hoc logic into solidity smart contract and make sure all of the logic can be executed in **a single transaction**